# Mapkit didSelectAnnotationView : How to get at custom properties?

Tags: ios

I am trying to open a detail view controller when a  user taps a push pin.

I have also defined a custom annotation and I want to pass some of its information into the detail view controller. It looks like this:

```
 @interface SquatAnnotationClass : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

NSString *name;
NSString *address;
NSString *gendered;
NSString *availability;
NSString *directions;
NSString *commments;



CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *gendered;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *availability;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *directions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *comments;





- (id)initWithLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) acoordinate;

// Other methods and properties.
@end
```

This is where I am trying to access them

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
```

Right now, when I try to reference them it doesn't know anything about them other than title.

My question is, how do i get at the properties of my custom annotation? For example, directions so that I may pass it into the detail controller.

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast the annotation object to your class:

```
SquatAnnotationClass *sac = (SquatAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;
NSLog(@"sac.name = %@", sac.name);
```